# Hot to set HTTP headers in Meteor for Graphlql request on custom domain

Tags: javascript, heroku, meteor, cors, graphql

it is my first time using Graphql in production and it is giving me the following problem.
The antecedents:

- It is a Meteor application that uses Apollo - Graphql to do search, Auth, etc.
- I am deploying on a heroku server.
- The DNS is in digitalocean and I use a custom domain.
- On the heroku server and on the localhost, everything works fine, no problem.

The problem:
when I used the custom domain, the content was blocked and a cors policy error appeared in the browser console, apparently a problem with the origin of the callback, so I investigated and configured the headers using the Meteor resources (webapp) and the source problem was solved, however it does not give me the Ok status, so the "OPTIONS" operation ends up blocking the other operations.

The code:

This code is running at: import/startup/server/register-api.js

```
WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "POST");
return next();
});
```

[This is the image of console browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Efx.png)
this is the bloqued operations:

```
General: request
Request URL: https://servername.herokuapp.com/graphql
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 34.193.254.1:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Header
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.domainname.co
Allow: GET, POST
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2018 17:13:52 GMT
Server: Cowboy
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Powered-By: Express

Request Header
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,meteor-login-token
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://www.domainname.co
Referer: http://www.domainname.co/search-panel?lat=xxxx&lng=xxx&address=xxxx&category=xxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36
```

thank you very much to all

Comment: express-graphql doesn’t handle OPTIONS requests (by design). See the discussion and solutions at https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/14#issuecomment-219863954. The gist of it is, you either want to update your current WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use code with something similar to https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/14#issuecomment-298489529 for handling OPTIONS requests — or else just install the npm cors package and follow the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight to configure it to handle OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i dont use express for up the server, im using the createApolloServer from  "meteor/apollo" package. Now im trying to use the express package like middleware and ApolloLink.